# How do I split a string into an array, maintaining the line-breaks?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to slice a Unicode string in Ruby.
The slicing should keep the invisible characters intact.

Here's an example of the input:

```
Foo\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
Bär 1.234 Foo test\r\n
blub
```

Which should become:

```
Array=["Foo\r\n\r\n\r\n","Bär","1.234,"Foo","test\r\n","blub"]
```

Basically I want to tokenize the string and keep the formatting intact.

When I do something like:

```
String.split(/ /)
```

I end up with something like:

```
Array=["Foo\r\n\r\n\r\nBär","1.234","Foo"]
```

And, something like:

```
String.split(/\W/)
```

kills the formatting.

Comment: If you're looking for a simple way to split a string into an array based on its line breaks, take a look at the Ruby `String.lines` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `split`, use `scan` for the first part:

```
text = "Foo\r\n\r\n\r\nBär 1.234 Foo test\r\nblub"
text.scan(/^.+[\r\n]*/)
=> ["Foo\r\n\r\n\r\n", "Bär 1.234 Foo test\r\n", "blub"]
```

Then conditionally apply your split like this:

```
text.scan(/^.+[\r\n]*/).map{ |s| s[' '] ? s.split(/ /) : s }.flatten
=> ["Foo\r\n\r\n\r\n", "Bär", "1.234", "Foo", "test\r\n", "blub"]
```

or:

```
text.scan(/^.+[\r\n]*/).flat_map{ |s| s[' '] ? s.split(/ /) : s }
=> ["Foo\r\n\r\n\r\n", "Bär", "1.234", "Foo", "test\r\n", "blub"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to go with the unicode:

```
s.split(/\u0020/)
```

it is not exactly the output you want, but it is very close, and then you can resort to using flat_map on it.